# How to keep a process (in this case scrnsave.scr” running on top of all other windows making them run in background?

Tags: batch-file, screensaver

I am attempting to keep the screen saver active manually for a predetermined amount of seconds so that I program can run in the background without displaying a bunch of trash data that it displays when it boots. In order to make a more seamless GUI for a kiosk

Currently I am running a batch script That turns off echo, manually start screensaver using the start command. Then I am using the time out function to set a predetermined amount of seconds until terminating the screensaver. I terminate the screensaver by using a visual basic script that outputs the up arrow key us ending the screensaver. Then I exit. Any ideas on how to keep this on top? I know that it is still running in the background if I exit the program really quickly I continue to see the countdown.

Comment: See my Topmost program https://pastebin.com/kL87SWe7. And to see window titles see https://pastebin.com/BfvdFkBq

Comment: You can launch the batch file from a vbscript to have it run in the background with no console window.